# How to display a error message to the user by redirecting to current page - django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a question that I feel like I solved before but for some reason, I just can't figure it out. I have a Django view that will update a users information that is stored in the database that involves the user entering his current password, a new password, and verification of the new password.

I have the processing complete for the situation where the user enters all of the correct information. I am not trying to add the else statements just in case the user does not enter the currently existing password or the passwords don't match.

In the two commented lines in the else statements is where I want to display the current HTML template with the form and have a message that displays a message that is assigned for different errors that exist.

```
if 'passwordSubmit' in request.POST:
    updatePassword = updatePasswordForm(request.POST)
    if updatePassword.is_valid():
        cd = updatePassword.cleaned_data
        old_password = cd['old_password']
        new_password = cd['new_password']
        verify_password = cd['verify_password']
        user = authenticate(username=currentUser.username, password=old_password)
        if user is not None:
            if new_password == verify_password:
                secure_password = make_password(new_password)
                update_user = currentUser
                update_user.password = secured_password
                update_user.save()
            else:
                message = 'The two passwords do not match'
                # if the passwords do no match
        else:
            message = 'The password entered does not match our records'
            # in case the old password is not what is saved in the database
```

Comment: in the view, you can return a variable via render or many ways that django provides access in the template

Comment: You can use messages framework of Django  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing manan_kalariya's line of thought add the message to the context you pass to the template.  Assuming you do something like this in your view:

```
return render(request, "customer/login.html", {"message":message})
```

then you could do this in your template:

```
{% if message %}<div>{{message}}</div>{% endif %}
```

And style it however you like and place it where you want with respect to the form.